# Stop jQuery.ajax() from passing parameters with "_json" as master parameter name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Assume we use jQuery.ajax() to POST data with two parameters, **game_id** and **player_id**.

When we use jQuery.ajax(), the server receives parameters like this:`{"_json"=>"game_id=4f6a593a8cb45b16c0000491&player_id=4f68ed4b8cb45b16c0000111"}`

We would like the server to receive parameters like this:

```
{"game_id=4f6a593a8cb45b16c0000491&player_id=4f68ed4b8cb45b16c0000111"}
```

Essentially, ajax() makes "_json" the master key for all parameters. Is there a way to prevent this, or are we doing something wrong?

Here's some specific code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  
        url: UPDATE_GAME_URL,  
        data: { "game_id" : game_id,
                "player_id" : get_player_id(),
                "turn_set" : JSON.stringify(turn_set) },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show some of your code. If you pass an object as `data` to any of the jQuery ajax calls it usually converts its elements to simple key/value pairs like in a normal non-ajaxed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does not contain any code that prefixes fields with `json_` so the problem is somewhere else.

However, you need to remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` to ensure the server parses the POST data correctly - you are not posting JSON after all.
If your server *does* expect a JSON payload (according to the string you expect to receive it doesn't!), you would have to use `data: JSON.stringify({...})` to ensure you actually send a JSON string instead of form-encoded key/value pairs.

Comment: Ahh, thanks ... we're on Rails 3.0.6. Maybe Rails is the culprit?

Comment: Even if you're a thief, we love you. This was the answer.

Comment: Quick q: do we need the dataType: 'json' bit still?

Comment: If the server always returns JSON it's a very good idea to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',  
    url: UPDATE_GAME_URL,  
    data: { "game_id" : game_id,
            "player_id" : get_player_id(),
            "turn_set" : turn_set },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

You don't need to stringify the `turn_set`, jQuery will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, but will this fix the main problem (i.e., eliminating "_json" as the master parameter)?

Comment: Give it a try to see what it does.

Comment: We did ... didn't solve the problem unless we're doing something wrong.

Comment: What was the parameter data this time when stringify was removed?